# Java 2D Graphics get image from URL instead of resource

Tags: java, drawing, 2d, java-2d

Alright so I've followed [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-F7z1xWS6o) tutorial of youtube for drawing with Java 2D Graphics, however how would I do it so it fetches the image from an URL instead of Resources ?

If you could please update and link me to the new code, that would be a +

Thank you VERY in advance

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Screen extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Screen() {
        try {
            image = Image.IO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/imagee.png"));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
       g.drawImage(image, 10, 10, null);
    }

}
```

I don't exactly know Java, I just need to do this for something

Comment: Create a URL instance and pass it to ImageIO.read...

Comment: If the code is an example from the tutorial, then the tutorial is wrong and should find a new one. Don't override paint, instead override paintComponent. You MUST call super.paint (or super.paintComponent if you've overridden paintComponent) in order to maintain the paint chain and prevent possible graphical glitches from occurring. It would also be easier to to use a JLabel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
image = Image.IO.read(new URL("http://..."));
```

FYI `Class#getResource` returns a `URL`

If the code is an example from the tutorial, then the tutorial is wrong and you should find a new one. Don't override `paint`, instead override `paintComponent`. You MUST call `super.paint` (or `super.paintComponent` if you've overridden `paintComponent`) in order to maintain the paint chain and prevent possible graphical glitches from occurring. It would also be easier to to use a `JLabel`...

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get an URL object:

> URL url = new URL("the-URL");
>
> BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);

Comment: Sorry, is the method read from ImageIO:BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read.(url);(without the last dot)

Comment: Already fixed. Both codes (MadProgrammer and mine) should work properly